# soft lock vs hard lock in hibernate terms

Tags: hibernate

I was reading about second level caching and I have come across the term soft lock. SO I was trying to articulate the difference between soft lock and hard lock and this is my understanding.Can someone comment on my understanding please.

Soft Lock: When they say soft lock its a lock that is applied on the record that is present in the cache. So for example, in case of Read/Write, if an item is soft locked and any other session tries to look for it, it has to go to DB to fetch that item.

Hard Lock: This is basically a lock that is applied on the DB tuple itself and any session that needs to read from or write to this tuple needs to wait for the transaction to complete and the hard lock to be released.

Regards,
Lalitha